# Is it worth notifying companies about reflected XSS that gets filtered by the XSS auditor?

Tags: xss, vulnerability

I am wondering if I should report a reflected XSS vulnerability if it gets filtered by the XSS auditor of browsers.

For example, if I find an XSS vulnerability in `www.website.tld/some-action/?productSku=tes"%20onload="alert(1)`, but the browser shows me the following auditor error: [image: reflected xss]

In my case the targeted website does not have the `X-XSS-Protection` header set, but most of the browsers enable XSS protection by default. I know I can try other things, like loading a malicious GIF file with JavaScript, but i'm just wondering if the `onload=alert(1)` above (which gets filtered) would also be considered a security issue, and why it would or wouldn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

New bypasses for the xss auditor are found on a regular basis, and there are browsers like FireFox, which still lack a built-in XSS auditor. Reflective XSS needs to be fixed because it is a weakness in the operation of the application.  Relying upon a 3rd party security system is... shaky at best.

When XSS is common place,  other vulnerabilities follow.

Comment: So if their bug bounty program states that reflected XSS needs to be reported, would you think that my example would indeed be categorized as reflected XSS?

Comment: @Tijme  Yes 100%,  try the same exploit in firefox.

Comment: I tried it in FireFox and it didn't work, but I forgot that the onload attribute doesn't trigger on divs. I tried it with onmouseover afterwards and it indeed works fine. Thanks!